# How can I assign text to a custom HSlider Value?

Tags: flash, builder

I would like the label to display custom values of the slider, for example

slider value equals 0 then label text is 250
Slider value is 1 then label text is 333
slider value is 2 then label text is 543
slider value is 3 then label text is 9342

I am new to this and any help is greatly appreciated. my sample code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Panel x="199" y="141" width="250" height="200">
    <s:HSlider id="ValueSlider" x="74" y="68" maximum="3" minimum="0" stepSize="1"/>
    <s:Label id="ValueLabel" x="109" y="38" text="Label"/>
</s:Panel>
```

Thanks to @Whiteagle this is were I am at now, but now Im getting a "Could not resolve  to a component implementation" error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.SliderEvent;
        protected function ValueSlider_changeHandler(event:SliderEvent):void
    {
        ValueLabel.text = ValueSlider.value;
            if(ValueSlider.value == "0")
            ValueLabel.text = "150";
            if(ValueSlider.value == "1")
            ValueLabel.text = "333";
            if(ValueSlider.value == "2")
            ValueLabel.text = "543";
            if(ValueSlider.value == "3")
            ValueLabel.text = "9342";
    }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<s:Panel x="199" y="141" width="250" height="200">
    <s:HSlider id="ValueSlider" x="74" y="68" maximum="5" minimum="0" stepSize="1"/>
    <s:Label id="ValueLabel" x="109" y="38" text="Label"/>
</s:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a change event and alter the text property of your label:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.events.SliderEvent;

        protected function ValueSlider_changeHandler(event:SliderEvent):void
        {
            ValueLabel.text = ValueSlider.value; // You could also use event.currentTarget or similar to obtain the element that dispatched the event, I prefered to refer to it directly for this example.
            // Add your logic here. For instance:
            if(ValueSlider.value == "0") // I'm using an if just for demonstration purposes, if you want to do one check per value you may want to consider using a switch.
                ValueLabel.text = "300";
                ...
        }

    ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <s:Panel x="199" y="141" width="250" height="200">
        <s:HSlider id="ValueSlider" x="74" y="68" maximum="3" minimum="0" stepSize="1" change="ValueSlider_changeHandler(event)" />
        <s:Label id="ValueLabel" x="109" y="38" text="Label"/>
    </s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: This will display hslider value when at 0 to be "0" not "250" as i need. The values i need to display are not incremental so looking for a way to assign a value to 0, 1, 2, and 3 to be displayed in the label.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that you needed to add your logic into the change handler, you just need to alter the line `ValueLabel.text = ValueSlider.value;` and adjust it to your needs. Check my edit above.

Comment: Also @Usoldier18 please keep in mind that I'm trying to teach you "how to fish", not "fishing for you".

Comment: yes I understand trying to learn to fish. my project has two sliders and multiple labels, i trying to get a small example that i can apply to the larger one by learning. Appreciate the help.